# How to define a different style on a TreeViewItem based on Type

Tags: wpf, xaml, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I have my own treeview implementation based on [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/atc_avalon_team/archive/2006/03/01/541206.aspx), but I have problems defining a different style based on what object type is in the treeviewitem. I know the simple way is to define a templateselector, but I can't figure out how this would work when you have two HierarchicalDataTemplates.

```
 <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type domainLayer:Folder}" ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BaseTypeConverter}}" />
 <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type domainLayer:Document}" ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BaseTypeConverter}}" />
```

I use these templates to lazy load my tree, which works fine. There's also a Style defined for all TreeListViewItems. Maybe there's a solution too, but I can't figure out how to define if my TreeListViewItem is either a Folder or a Document.

Any help is much appreciated. If you need more code, just let me know!

Update 10:40am:

In a Style the row is defined for every TreeListViewItem:

```
<Style x:Key="cxc" TargetType="{x:Type local:TreeListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="TradeGothic LT" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14px" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource TextBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="OnItemMouseDoubleClick" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:TreeListViewItem}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Border Name="Bd"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <GridViewRowPresenter x:Name="PART_Header"
                                                Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                                Columns="{Binding Path=Columns,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:TreeListView}}}"
                                                />
                    </Border>
                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost" />
                </StackPanel>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
<!-- ... -->
```

When I copy the template (everything in the StackPanel tag) to the HierarchicalDataTemplate I get an error: Cannot find the static member 'BackgroundProperty' on the type 'ContentPresenter'.

Comment: It looks like I've found a solution, i.e. get rid of the style and define the template inside the HierarchicalDataTemplate. Like so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726318/how-can-i-specify-which-treeviewitem-style-template-for-a-treeviewitem-generated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be a little bit confused by the different `Template`s that WPF provides. First, we can define a `Style` for the `TreeViewItem` (the `ItemContainerStyle`), the data item 'container'. Then we can define a `DataTemplate` for the data item that appears within the container (the `ItemTemplate`), or `HierarchicalDataTemplate` in your case.

So don't try to put your data item `Binding` in the `ItemContainerStyle` and don't put your UI element `Binding` in the `DataTemplate` and you should be fine. Note that you can supply one `DataTemplate`/`HierarchicalDataTemplate` *without setting their `x:Key` property* for each data type in your collection and there is no need to use a `DataTemplateSelector`... let WPF do the implicit selecting of `DataTemplate`s based on the data item's types. Here is a simple example:

In code:

```
public class BaseClass { }

public class ClassA : BaseClass { }

public class ClassB : BaseClass { }

...

public Observablecollection<BaseClass> Items { get ; set; }
```

In XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DataTypes:ClassA}">
            <Ellipse Fill="Red" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DataTypes:ClassB}">
            <Rectangle Fill="Blue" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

This `ListBox` would display red circles for the `ClassA` items and blue rectangles for the `ClassB` items. You can do a similar thing for your folders and files

Comment: Hi Sheridan, thanks for replying. Thanks for clearing this up, because I really was confused about it. However, I don't think this would work for what I want as I need quite a lot of overlap. But, I have fixed it. I will answer to myself.

Comment: Althoug this works now, I have to come back to my statement as this isn't quite the proper way: the problem I've encountered now is that for an exact same TreeView, but with different objects, I'd have to create a complete new Style for these objects. Any thoughts?

Comment: Remember, not `Style`s...  data objects <==> `DataTemplate`s. You'll need to create a new `DataTemplate` for each data type that you use, but I fail to see this as a problem... just the norm.

Comment: Maybe I'm taking the too easy way out of this, but what I've tried is to copy the Template code in the Style to the HierarchicalDataTemplate. I got quite some errors on the styling (e.g. the Background property), but maybe that's what you're saying: just copy the template without the UI styling. I'll try that first. Thanks again!

Comment: Dude, it seems like you still haven't quite got it yet... there's really no need for `DataTemplateSelector`s, or `DataTrigger`s to do any of this. All you need is a `DataTemplate`/`HierarchicalDataTemplate` for each data type and that's it. Still, if you're happy with what you have, that's fine.

Comment: Yeah, I've got that. I have no Selector and no DataTrigger. A very simple HDataTemplate. The only thing that doesn't work now is that I have the original togglebutton right before my own togglebutton. What I don't get exactly is how the Style declaration got rid of the original togglebutton. Working on that ... but looks promising. If you want I can send you what I've got.

Comment: From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewrowpresenter(v=vs.110).aspx): *The GridViewRowPresenter and GridViewHeaderRowPresenter classes support the GridView view mode for a ListView control*. Wouldn't a `Grid` with [`Grid.IsSharedSizeScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.issharedsizescope(v=vs.110).aspx)`="True"` be easier and more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem as follows. In the aforementioned Style I've added a new MultiDataTrigger:

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition
            Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Header, Converter={StaticResource IsFolder}}"
            Value="False" />
        <Condition
            Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsSelected}"
            Value="True" />
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter TargetName="Bd"
            Property="Background"
            Value="{StaticResource HighlightBackgroundBrush}" />
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

This seems to work and looks like the proper solution. Thanks, Sheridan for the background on this.